# Why is the Wonder Woman question on hold?

Tags: discussion

[How is Wonder Woman related to the Amazons of Greek Mythology and Atlantis?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2240/is-diana-themyscira-real-if-so-is-atlantis-real)

The question is quite clear and relevant.  This topic was covered by legit scholars when I was studying Classics at University, and was seen as a valuable "in" to connect young people with the actual canon.

Not to mention, it is sure to draw some of the Wonder Woman web traffic, and provides a landing page for interested parties to learn more about the actual, mythological roots of Wonder Woman.

Comment: What next we start having thor questions?  I guess there is a thor tag ;)  I'm not sure if the question should be edited to include wonder women because I don't know who Diana Themyscira is.

Comment: The question (as it stands) is on hold for being unclear (not for being off-topic). As William said, as the very least, the question should be edited to mention Wonder Woman and a little bit of context.

Comment: If you edited the question so it asks "what is the relationship between atlantis and Themyscira", and if you added some background information explaining what Themyscira was, that would go a long way towards getting the question reopened.

Comment: Note that [this site already has a question about whether Atlantis is "real"](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1603/62), and if you're interested in talking about Atlantis that would be the place to do it.

Comment: Still confused by the question. I would add a sentence explaining who "Diana Themyscira" is, as "Diana Themyscira" is from Wonder Woman, which is outside of the scope of this site. I'm also confused by the sentence "If so, is Atlantis an actual mythological location?": are you talking about Plato's Atlantis, or something from wonder woman?

Comment: Is our function not also to clarify and demystify?  Someone would only ask this question is they knew nothing about the mythology of the Amazons.  I'm not sure why asking about the Amazons through a modern adaptation is so problematic.  I think explaining that "Diana Themyscira" is not a real mythological figure is absolutely part of the purpose of the site.

Comment: @DukeZhou I'm saying is that the question "If so, is Atlantis an actual mythological location?" is very confusing: are you talking abut Plato's Atlantis (in which case this question is a duplicate), or are you talking about something from Wonder Woman? And I hardly think it's unreasonable to ask the OP to add a sentence explaining who "Diana Themyscira" is from the perspective of the Wonder Woman universe, especially since it would help people unfamiliar with Wonder Woman answer the question.

Comment: I see.  I wasn't thinking from the perspective of those who don't know anything about Wonder Woman!  (In terms of Atlantis though, I was hoping "actual mythological location" would be enough: answer it wasn't but derives from Plato and Thera has been proposed.)  I'll take another pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm about to cast the fifth reopen vote, so I might as well give my thoughts on the question.

The [first version](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/revisions/2240/1) of the question was

> ## Is Diana themeskara real?if so is Atlantis real?
>
> Does anyone have any real proof not from comics or movies

When I see that, I think of someone asking if these things are - well, real objects in our world. It reads like someone asking if Bigfoot is real - especially as the reference to "comics or movies" seemed to suggest that the OP dismissed those as being fictional representations. So at first glance, it looks nothing like a question about mythology.

*However*, I wasn't sure that that's what the question was actually asking. I was extrapolating. When in a situation like this, I'd vote to close as Unclear What You're Asking, so I waited (not wanting to mod-hammer it) and then cast the fifth close vote (the [second version](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/revisions/2240/2), after an edit, was no clearer, though still helpful).

After that, several edits (mostly by yourself) made the question much clearer. I don't know if this is what the author intended, and I'm wary of changing the intent of a question like this. However, the author deleted their account, and the question in [its current form](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/revisions/2240/8) is both clear and on-topic:

> ## How is Wonder Woman related to the Amazons of Greek Mythology and Atlantis?
>
> Does anyone have any real proof not from comics or movies that Diana of Themyscira is an actual figure from mythology?  How does Atlantis relate to this?
>
> ---
>
> For background, [Diana of Themyscira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman) is name of the modern superhero, Wonder Woman.  In the comic books, [Themyscira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Themyscira_(DC_Comics)) is the capital of the Amazons, and depicted as a mysterious island with a hidden location, similar to Atlantis.

You can't get much clearer than that. Question reopened.